# karate- checking whole response with jason schema getting error gherkin.lexer.LexingError

Tags: json, karate

- def validbalance1 = """{  "Account": { "Name": "#string", "Id": "#string"}"""
- def validbalance2 = """{
          "Account": {
             "Name": "#string",
             "Id": "#string"
          }"""

i am defining json in my feature file, but getting error in validbalance2 that is gherkin lexing error . i understand that i am getting error if my entire json is not in one line. But want to be like validbalance2.

Comment: validbalnce2 is in json formatted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got the answer:

https://github.com/intuit/karate#multi-line-expressions

""" need to be start in new line